# Cannot restore TWRP Backup because it cannot mount internal storage after reboot

Tags: twrp

I don't set pin/password for my device.

The first time I use TWRP, it cannot mount internal storage. So I go ahead and wipe the storage. This allows internal storage to mount and I can create NAndroid backup for my phone.

Then I restart the phone and go through the setup process from beginning.

Then I restart into recovery (TWRP) again, it asks for the encryption password again. So I in effect cannot see what's on my internal storage and cannot see how can I ever restore such backup I made earlier.

What did I do wrong? How can I backup and restore using TWRP without setting pin/password for my device?

(For the record, set 0000 as lock screen PIN and use it as decryption password doesn't work for me)

Comment: From TWRP Options check if storage is mounted or not, the second tile. You probably did that but it is not clear from the question

Comment: either TWRP is able to decrypt or you must format userdata partition each time