# TWRP cannot find backup

Tags: backup, twrp, restore

Motorola G4 Play, formerly with LineageOS/14.1 + TWRP 3.2

Made the mistake of trying /e/OS but before I did, I copied 2-TWRP full backups and a lot of other pics and data to my Mint 20 laptop. I have formatted an SD card to ext4 and created the `.TWRP/BACKUP` as suggested on another thread here from 6-years back and also tried the suggestion from another one here today. [Cannot restore TWRP Backup because it cannot mount internal storage after reboot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/229206) and the sdcard is mounted as suggested there.

Running TWRP I can see the sdcard and the `TWRP` folder (no preceeding dot shown), but nothing beyond that and I am unable to navigate.

How can I get to the backup to restore my phone to LineageOS. Should never have left, ahh, hindsight.

Comment: MicroSD Card (ext4) probably will not mounted by vold, format MicroSD Card (vfat) or mount yourself via terminal. btw it's */external_sd* (*/sdcard* is */data/media*)

Comment: Could be DM-Verity blocking the install. The [1]: https://twrp.me/FAQ/ states probably caused by dm-verity one of the possible causes of that.

> Android 6.0 or higher, the. 
> device maker has enabled dm-> 
> verity as a security measure. > > The device will signature > 
> check. blocks of data on the. 
> system partition during boot. 
> at.the block level. The usage. 
> of dm-verity prevents TWRP. 
> from.being able to. 
> successfully. restore a normal. 
> system backup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to you both, but it is fixed. I removed the SD card and copied the 2-backup files to the Root of it and put it back in. I was connected via USB to the phone so I copied the 2-backup files to a bunch of different Folders within the Internal Memory to try and see where TWRP was looking by defualt.

***Slapping my forehead moment now!***

Straight off, **Internal memory, Recovery Folder** and TWRP found them there without any Navigation. Did not think of that earlier but patently obvious now. Dang hindsight -- again.